# How to highlight some selected texts in PDF with PyPDF2?

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I have carefully read the documentation and APIs of PyPDF2. But I cannot find the information I need. I want to highlight some text information in my PDF with Python code. For example, highlight the author area of a paper. Can anyone give me some advice on the potential usage of PyPDF I ignored or other practical python library on PDF?